# Set background color to transparent in safari in css

Tags: css, safari

is there a way to set background-color in safari to transparent? Currently my png is displayed with a white background instead of transparent.

I've tried:
`background-color: transparent;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
appearance: none;`

and even 
`-khtml-background-color: transparent;`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seemed to be repoducable with any png image with a transparent background.loaded with an url not image tag. Testet with ipad/Safari (*important: Not windows safari version)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your CSS, but if you've saved your image with a colored background (e.g. red/white/yellow) it's not possible to "overwrite" this color using CSS. Therefore you need to make sure the background of the image is transparent.

Take a look at the following page to get an idea of what I described.
https://www.causevox.com/blog/using-the-right-logo-image-transparent-png/

Comment: Hi, sorry but i'm not using a colored background ^^.  It seemed to be a problem with Safari.

Comment: What’s the size of your image? @rakowu

Comment: 310x65 but it scale with 100% width / height auto for responsive.